# can we hide required standard field or make it read only

Tags: administration, admin, system-admin

can we hide required standard field or make it read only
since that fields auto populates the name once the user save the field,in order to make the user less confusing

Comment: Please mention the field name, it depends on the field itself.

Comment: unfortunately with standard page layouts you cannot remove or prefill or make it optional / readonly .. some options - use VF pages.. or give custom New button/link with URL hack to pre fill the field (this will be classic only)

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, no. Standard required fields are required for proper system operation and cannot be disabled in any way. You could choose to write a Visualforce page or two, but it's usually not worth the effort. Instead, some amount of training should be invested in the users. You can also add an Inline Help Text to most standard fields these days if you want to provide on-screen instructions about the usage of a field.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a workaround with flexipages. You can use them to make the UI behavior of the field as read-only.